# Using multiprossing and Queue deal with files of large numpy array

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have a lot of HDF5 files on disk (**compressed by gzip so reading is CPU-intensive, each file contains about 80MB data and needs about 300ms to load**）
 and want to load data into memory using multi-process.I use multi-process to load file and push them into a Queue, and meanwhile the main process read data from the queue.

**the main process:**

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import h5py
import glob
import time

def read_file(filename):
    reader = h5py.File(filename)
    data = {}
    for key in reader.keys():
        data[key] = np.array(reader.get(key))
    return data

def producer(filename_queue, data_queue):
    total_begin = time.time()
    while True:
        begin = time.time()
        f = filename_queue.get_nowait()
        if f is False:
            break
        data = read_file(f)
        data_queue.put(data)
        time_cost = time.time() - begin
        print "Time cost of producer: %.2f ms" % (
             time_cost * 1000)
    total_time_cost = time.time() - total_begin
    print "Avg time cost of producer: %.2f ms" % (
        total_time_cost / len(filenames) * 1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    process_num = 1

    filenames = glob.glob("./data/*.hdf5")
    filename_queue = multiprocessing.Queue(len(filenames) + process_num)
    for f in filenames:
        filename_queue.put(f)
    for _ in range(process_num):
        filename_queue.put(False)

    data_queue = multiprocessing.Queue(1024)

    processes = []

    for _ in range(process_num):
        processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(
            target=producer, args=(filename_queue, data_queue)))
    for p in processes:
        p.daemon = True
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # Reading data from queue
    total_begin = time.time()
    for _ in xrange(len(filenames)):
        begin = time.time()
        data = data_queue.get()
        time_cost = time.time() - begin
        print "Time cost of consumer: %.2f ms" % (
            time_cost * 1000)
    toal_time_cost = time.time() - total_begin
    print "Avg time cost of consumer: %.2f ms" % (
        total_time_cost / len(filenames) * 1000)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

And the results (process_num=1) is:

```
Time cost of producer: 390.58 ms
Time cost of consumer: 561.85 ms
Time cost of producer: 389.11 ms
Time cost of consumer: 569.67 ms
Time cost of producer: 402.26 ms
Time cost of consumer: 568.95 ms
Time cost of producer: 387.32 ms
Avg time cost of producer: 559.29 ms
Avg time cost of consumer: 560.05 ms
```

For each step, consumer takes more time than producer, but the average time is equal.
Set process_num to 2 I got:

```
Time cost of producer: 381.25 ms
Time cost of producer: 479.66 ms
Time cost of consumer: 573.43 ms
Time cost of producer: 377.40 ms
Time cost of producer: 380.14 ms
Time cost of producer: 490.50 ms
Time cost of producer: 391.92 ms
Time cost of consumer: 682.74 ms
Time cost of producer: 389.05 ms
Avg time cost of producer: 205.45 ms
Time cost of producer: 480.88 ms
Avg time cost of producer: 206.14 ms
Time cost of consumer: 573.75 ms
Time cost of consumer: 256.17 ms
Time cost of consumer: 260.29 ms
Time cost of consumer: 260.84 ms
Time cost of consumer: 256.11 ms
......
Time cost of consumer: 271.39 ms
Time cost of consumer: 273.18 ms
Time cost of consumer: 286.35 ms
Avg time cost of consumer: 384.83 ms
```

When the producer processes terminnated, the consumer process (main process) still needs 270ms to get data from data_queue, maybe time is wasted on memory copy (write and read of pipe) because of large data size (80MB per file).

Is there a more effective way to solve the problem？